# convert aes encryption in JAVA to node

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, aes

I have a script in java

```
private static final String ALGO = "AES";

public static String encrypt(String Data,String secretKeyPhrase) throws Exception {

    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyPhrase.getBytes(), ALGO);

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encVal);
    encryptedValue= URLEncoder.encode(encryptedValue, "UTF-8");
    return encryptedValue;
}


public static void main(String [] ar) throws Exception{
    String result2=AESUtil.encrypt("3483", "BDFHJLNPpnljhfdb");
    System.out.println(result2);
}
```

i need to replicate this in node i do this

```
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('3483', 'BDFHJLNPpnljhfdb').toString();
```

console.log(ciphertext);

in the java result show me

```
3483
```

sAllhJ7zLxBKr8hJ7tLf9w%3D%3D

but in node

```
3483
```

U2FsdGVkX19Z/mnjJy3hYDcXfWnH5eayYngWMtUT1lw=

what i am doing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: "in the php script"...what PHP script??

Comment: sorry is java not php

Comment: In the CryptoJS code pass the key not as string but as `WordArray`, use the Utf8 encoder for this. Also specify explicitly the ECB mode. Note: It's better to specify explicitly mode and padding in the Java code, e.g. `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`, otherwise provider dependent default values are used (for the SunJCE provider ECB and PKCS5Padding). By the way, the ECB mode is insecure, better is CBC, even better GCM. The last two use an IV/nonce.

Answer (score 0):

hi i can encrypt with node this is the script

```
function encrypt(plaintext) {
  var data = plaintext;
  var iv = new Buffer(0);
  const key = 'BDFHJLNPpnljhfdb'
  var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ecb',new Buffer(key),new Buffer(iv))
  var crypted = cipher.update(data,'utf-8','base64')
  crypted += cipher.final('base64')
  return crypted;
}
```

and the result is sAllhJ7zLxBKr8hJ7tLf9w==

Answer (score 0):

this is another way with cripto-js

```
function encrypt(plaintext) {
  var keyUtf8 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("BDFHJLNPpnljhfdb")
  var result = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, keyUtf8,{ mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,  
  keySize: 128 }).toString();
  return result;
}

function decrypt(ciphertext) {
  var keyUtf8 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("BDFHJLNPpnljhfdb")
  var encrypted=ciphertext;
  encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, keyUtf8, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,  
  keySize: 128 });
  var result = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(encrypted).toString(); 
  return result;
}

var ciphertext=encrypt("3483");
// result sAllhJ7zLxBKr8hJ7tLf9w==
var ciphertext=decrypt("sAllhJ7zLxBKr8hJ7tLf9w==");
// result 3483
```